# Steam Input causes SEGFAULT whenever I call GetAnalogActionData

Tags: c++, input, sdl-2, steam, steamworks-api

I'm making a game using SDL2, with controller support through Steamworks, and my program SEGFAULTs whenever GetAnalogActionData is called.
I'm compiling with MinGW g++ through MSYS2, using Steamworks API version 157.

I know I should store the handles once, but since it segfaults the second I try and read from the data, it never gets read again. I just want to figure out why this isn't working.

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <steam/steam_api.h>

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
bool isRunning = true;
using namespace std;

int init() {

    // Initialize Steam API
    if (!SteamAPI_Init()) {
        SDL_LogCritical(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Failed to initialize Steam API!");
        return 1;
    }
    // Initialize Steam Input
    if (!SteamInput()->Init(false)) {
        SDL_LogCritical(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_INPUT, "Failed to initialize Steam Input!");
        return 1;
    }

    {
        int res = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
        if (res < 0) {
            SDL_LogCritical(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Failed to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
            return res;
        }
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(">:(", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 640, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        SDL_LogCritical(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Failed to create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (renderer == nullptr) {
        SDL_LogCritical(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Failed to create renderer: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Log("initialized");

    return 0;
}

void shutdown() {
    SDL_Log("shutting down");
    SDL_Quit();
    SteamAPI_Shutdown();
    SDL_Log("goodnight");
}

void tick() {
    SDL_Event ev;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev)) {
        switch (ev.type) {
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
                // fallthrough if event is closing the window
                if (ev.window.event != SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) { break; }
            case SDL_QUIT: {
                isRunning = false;
                return;
                break;
            }
            case SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            case SDL_JOYBUTTONUP: {
                const char* buttonName = SDL_GameControllerGetStringForButton((SDL_GameControllerButton)ev.cbutton.button);
                printf("Button %s %s\n", buttonName, (ev.cbutton.state ? "DOWN" : "UP"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    SteamAPI_RunCallbacks();

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

#ifdef USE_STEAM
    SteamAPI_RunCallbacks();
#endif // USE_STEAM

    // render
    SDL_Rect rect = {100, 100, 480, 480 };
    InputAnalogActionHandle_t AnalogControls = SteamInput()->GetAnalogActionHandle ("AnalogControls");
    InputActionSetHandle_t GameControls = SteamInput()->GetActionSetHandle("GameControls");
    InputHandle_t controllers[STEAM_INPUT_MAX_COUNT]{};
    SteamInput()->GetConnectedControllers(controllers);
    SteamInput()->ActivateActionSet(controllers[0], GameControls);
    InputAnalogActionData_t data = SteamInput()->GetAnalogActionData(controllers[0], AnalogControls);
    printf("data: { %f, %f }\n", data.x, data.y);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, uint8_t(data.x * float(0xFF)), uint8_t(data.y * float(0xFF)), 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
#ifdef NDEBUG
    GLenum err = glGetError();
    if (err != 0) SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_VIDEO, "%x %s", err, glewGetErrorString(err));
#endif
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Log("running");
#ifdef NDEBUG
    SDL_LogSetAllPriority(SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_DEBUG);
#endif
    {
        int i = init();
        if (i) return i;
    }

    while (isRunning) tick();

    shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

The debugger is giving me my values:

- `controllers[0]` is `319124578728929405`
- `AnalogControls` is `1`
- `GameControls` is `1`

I'm developing using the default *Spacewar* appid, here's my IGA file (`game_actions_480.vdf`):

```
"In Game Actions"
{
    "actions"
    {
        "GameControls"
        {
            "title"                 "#Set_GameControls"
            "StickPadGyro"
            {
                "AnalogControls"
                {
                    "title"         "#Action_AnalogControls"
                    "input_mode"    "joystick_move"
                }
            }
            "Button"
            {
                "jump"  "#Action_Jump"
            }
        }
        "MenuControls"
        {
            "title"                 "#Set_MenuControls"
            "Button"
            {
                "menu_up"       "#Action_MenuUp"
                "menu_down"     "#Action_MenuDown"
                "menu_left"     "#Action_MenuLeft"
                "menu_right"    "#Action_MenuRight"
                "menu_select"   "#Action_MenuSelect"
                "menu_cancel"   "#Action_MenuCancel"
            }
        }
    }
    "localization"
    {
        "english"
        {
            "Title_Config1"     "Officially Configurated Configuration"
            "Description_Config1"   "sdalskdjaksjda."

            "Set_GameControls"          "In-Game Controls"
            "Set_MenuControls"          "Menu Controls"

            "Action_AnalogControls"     "Analog Controls"

            "Action_Jump"               "Jump"

            "Action_MenuUp"             "Menu Up"
            "Action_MenuDown"           "Menu Down"
            "Action_MenuLeft"           "Menu Left"
            "Action_MenuRight"          "Menu Right"
            "Action_MenuSelect"         "Menu Select"
            "Action_MenuCancel"         "Menu Cancel"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The cause is in the code you don't show us. Please show the shortest snippet of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Snippet's a risky word. You're better off with a small-as-possible complete program. Something folk out here can drop directly into their tools, build, and experiment on, assuming they have all of the required libraries. Use [mre] (MRE) for inspiration. The true beauty of making a MRE is odds are good while making this micro-program you'll spot what went wrong and fix it yourself.

Comment: Here's a 1-file MRE. Updated original post.

Comment: You do not use the return value from `GetConnectedControllers`. It tells you how many handles were written to your array. While that may not be the issue, it certainly appears to be an incorrect use of the API.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger, if not do do so and check the return value for functions returning pointers. Eg. `SDL_GameControllerGetStringForButton`. If any of them is nullptr then don't dereference them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit late, but I eventually figured it out and forgot to answer my own question!

As it turns out (I figured this out by reading the docs) Steamworks provides an alternative header, called `steam_api_flat.h`, providing a C API for use with other compilers/languages. My code looks like this:

```cpp
InputDigitalActionData_t data = SteamAPI_ISteamInput_GetDigitalActionData(SteamAPI_SteamInput(), activeSteamControllerHandle, h);
```

Hopefully this helps somebody out.

Answer (score 0):

This is really unfortunate; I was able to solve the problem by using Clang++ (MSVC backend) instead of g++. I'm going to need to look into this further, but for now, using MSVC ""solves"" the issue. I really need to use g++, so any advice is appreciated.